# How do I make a vue component render anywhere?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I would like to know how do I make a [vue](/questions/tagged/vue) component render anywhere without having the need to being put inside an element with an `id="app"`.

I have 4 components and one div with `id="app"` when I make a another element with `id="app"` and put another vue component in there the others stop working.

Answer (score 1):

You don't create a new HTML element (tag) with `id="app"` because:

1. `id` is unique, you can't have more than 1.
2. You have to use this `id` or reference in any part of your web page, but you have to know that everything related to `vue` must go inside it.

So, if you have a page where you have more than 1 component, you have to have a parent element with `id="app"` or whatever you choose to use as reference.

For example:

```html
<body id="app">
    <div>
        <vue-component-a />
        <vue-component-b />
        <vue-component-c />
        <vue-component-d />
    </div>
</body>
```

Or the way most used is:

```html
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <vue-component-a />
        <vue-component-b />
        <vue-component-c />
        <vue-component-d />
    </div>
</body>
```